# write settings for http2 session using nghttp2

Tags: c++11, http2, nghttp2

I am using nghttp2 library in its c++ wrapper for building an application

I would need to modify settings frame when creating the connection. Looking at API [libnghttp2_asio](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/libnghttp2_asio.html#client-api)

I don't see any way to write settings frame.

Could someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance and regards